# Javafx popup font is bold, how to set it as normal text

Tags: javafx, groovy

see my screenshot, the popup font and normal label font is diff, how to make them same

[image]

here is my code:

```
class TestPopupTextBoldBug extends Application {
    @Override
    void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox() {{
            children.add(new Label("here is normal text"))
        }}
        Popup pp = new Popup()
        pp.content.add(new VBox() {
            {
                children.add(new Label("here is popup text"))
            }
        })
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600)
        stage.setScene(scene)
        stage.show()
        pp.show(stage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try styling your Label CSS? [http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part4/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing a difference is because the Label on popup doesn't have a background color.

The VBox you have added as a parent to the Label is of transparent background.

You can add a background color by using css:

```
vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");
```